# Wordpress sidebar shows up in View Page Source but not live page...sometimes

Tags: php

I'm starting a redesign of our site, and I didn't get very far before I ran into a roadblock. I created four dynamic sidebars in the PHP, and called them all in the index. When I load the index, only three show up. For some other people it's four, and for some other people it's three. Either way, the fourth sidebar shows up when you view the page source, but just not on the live site.

I've cleared my cache numerous times, including with and without WP Super Cache going.

Here's the site: http://dev.greyinkstudios.com

And the functions.php call:

```
    // Register widgetized areas
add_action( 'init', 'theme_widgets_init' );
function theme_widgets_init() {
    // Area 1
    register_sidebar( array (
    'name' => 'Find Us',
    'id' => 'findus',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => "</div>",
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
  ) );

    // Area 2
    register_sidebar( array (
    'name' => 'Conventions',
    'id' => 'cons',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => "</div>",
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
  ) );

    //Area 3
    register_sidebar( array (
    'name' => 'Support WoBG',
    'id' => 'support',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => "</div>",
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
  ) );

     //Area 4
    register_sidebar( array (
    'name' => 'Advertisement',
    'id' => 'ads',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => "</div>",
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
  ) );
  } // end theme_widgets_init
```

And the code where I call it in the index (originally I had used the IDs to call them, but that caused only the first two sidebars to show, for some reason. So I switched to names.):

```
    <!-- #content -->

 <?php // get_sidebar(); ?> 
    <div id="sidebar-findus" class="sidebar">

        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'Find Us' ); ?>

    </div>
<div id="sidebar-cons" class="sidebar">

    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'Conventions' ); ?>

</div>

<div id="sidebar-support" class="sidebar">

    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'Support WoBG' ); ?>

</div>

<div id="sidebar-ads" class="sidebar">

    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'Advertisement' ); ?>

</div>
```

I ran it through the W3 validator, and the only exceptions it threw up were for the Comic Easel plug-in, and they were for unparsed ampersands. But when I went digging into the code, they were in fact `&amp;` so that wasn't the case.

Either way, I disabled the plug-in, and it still did the exact same thing. So I'm at a loss!

Thanks in advance!